# Android How to get key code events from Softkeboard

Tags: android, keyboard

Here I am referring to Softkeyboard sample application from Android. How can we get the keycode events in an application? As the Softkeyboard/android softkeyboard is running as a service, so how it will return pressed keycode events back to the application? Actually i want to capture the pressed key events from the softkeypad and sent it over a socket 
please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should override onKeyDown event and then check what keycode you are looking for. In developer.android.com number of keycode is available so you can have it. Please feel free to ask, if you want in detail.

Comment: onkeydown is not getting invoked while typing thruogh the softkeyboard
.Even i tried lot but don't know how to handle the softkeyboard event